# How to format Date-String (ddMMyy) to Date-String (yyMMdd) in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column named "date" with type varchar and the dates format is: "ddMMyy" but to use 'between', I need to get the date to the format "yyMMdd".

I have tried around for 2 hours but couldn't solve it, thanks for your help.

Comment: The better question is, why are you storing a date as a `varchar` and not a `date`?

Comment: Storing dates in columns of the appropriate data type (i.e. `DATETIME` or `DATE` etc) makes working with dates MUCH easier, including allowing the `BETWEEN` operator to work as expected.

Comment: Also, if you've been trying, what have you tried so far? Please include your attempts in your question. Thanks

Comment: Also - why are you using such a "generic" name for your column as `date` - that will collide with the T-SQL reserved keyword `DATE` for the datatype..... you should use **something MORE appropriate** for your problem domain, e.g. `HireDate` (if you're dealing with employees), `SaleDate` (if you're in e-commerce) etc.

Comment: Once you're storing your data in a suitable data type, if formatting matters, you can then handle that in your presentation (application) layer. SQL Server should be handling the data, and the application the display; in an ideal world. You'll find things far easier if you use the correct data types, and the right tools for the job.

Comment: Guys, I DIDNT create this database and as it has over 1.000.000 entries, I wont change anything on it, I just need a way to convert it on the fly because I am the guy who needs to live with this shitty convention

Comment: Could you at least update your post with what you've tried so far then please? And, it might be worth talking to your DBA to get the data changed, if you can't do it.

Answer (score 3):

Fix your data structure!  You should be able to do:

```
update t
    set datecol = convert(date, datecol, 104);  -- this format seems to work

alter table t alter column datecol date;

alter table t add datecol_ddmmyy as (replace(convert(varchar(8), datecol, 104), '.', '');
```

Voila!  The column now works correctly as a date.  And you have another column that formats the date as a string.

Comment: Thanks but I can not make any changes to the Database, it has over 1.000.000 entries and a lot of systems are based upon this table, I just need a way to convert on the fly. (No, i didnt create this table)

Comment: @ZesaRex . . . Well, the `convert()` function pretty much tells you what you need to do to convert the value to a date, so it can be compared correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have separators between your date components then I think Gordon Linoff's answer will work fine. (I know you said you can't alter the structure of your table, but you can at least use the expression he provided for converting date strings into proper dates.) But my understanding of your question was that your dates are actually six-character strings with no separators (e.g., 010199), and I got an error when I tried using [date style 104](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with data like that. Unfortunately that format doesn't seem to match any of the predefined styles given at that link, so I think you might have to resort to string manipulation to rearrange your dates into `yyMMdd` (ISO) format and convert from there. For instance:

```
declare @Table table ([date] varchar(6));
insert @Table values ('010101'), ('010110'), ('010149'), ('010150'), ('010199');

select
    [date], 
    ConvertedDate = convert(date, 
        substring([date], 5, 2) + 
        substring([date], 3, 2) + 
        substring([date], 1, 2), 12) 
from 
    @Table;
```

On my database this yields:

```
date    ConvertedDate
010101  2001-01-01
010110  2010-01-01
010149  2049-01-01
010150  1950-01-01
010199  1999-01-01
```

Note that since your database is using two-digit years, SQL Server uses a fence date to determine whether it should interpret a year as belonging to the 20th or 21st century. In my case, as you can deduce from the result set above, it's 2049. You can review [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-two-digit-year-cutoff-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017#TsqlProcedure) for information on querying and changing this setting (though I assume changing it is probably out of the question in your case).

Hopefully the database setting corresponds to the logic being used by whatever software is populating this database, but if not, and if you're not able to bring them into sync, then you'll have to update the `ConvertedDate` expression shown above to manually compute the century, and use style 112 instead of 12 to indicate the presence of a four-digit year. Something like this, perhaps:

```
declare @TwoDigitYearCutoff int = 90;
select
    [date], 
    ConvertedDate = convert(date, 
        case when convert(int, substring([date], 5, 2)) <= @TwoDigitYearCutoff then '20' else '19' end +
        substring([date], 5, 2) + 
        substring([date], 3, 2) + 
        substring([date], 1, 2), 112) 
from 
    @Table;
```

This is all rather messy, of course, but I'm not sure of a better way to do it. Good luck.